# configure XADatasource in REDHAT JBoss EAP 7.0 for Mariadb

Tags: jdbc, jboss, mariadb, redhat

I wanted to configure XA datasource for Mariadb in REDHAT JBoss EAP 7.0. I

I have created a non-XA datasource with below details and connection is working fine.

Driver: mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1

Connection URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test

But when I tried to create new XA datasource for distributed transactions then it fails with error detail.
Unexpected HTTP response: 500
    Request
    {
        "address" => [
            ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
            ("xa-data-source" => "MysqlXADS1")
        ],
        "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
    }

```
Response<br>

Internal Server Error<br>
{`enter code here`
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0042: failed to match                 
      pool. Check JndiName: java:/MysqlXADS1",
     "rolled-back" => true
  }
```

Configuration Details :
Driver: mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar_com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource_5_1
Url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/test
Valid Connection Checker: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker
Exception Sorter: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter

Answer (score 0):

JBoss EAP support for `MariaDB` started on version 7.0 so your version is not a problem.

From the error **WFLYJCA0040: failed to invoke operation: WFLYJCA0042: failed to match pool. Check JndiName**, and assuming the jdbc name is **correctly assigned**, I believe your issue will be solved on step 1.3 and 2, as below:

1. When setting up a data source on JBoss EAP 7.0:

   - deploy the driver
   - create the datasource
   - Verify the pool size, removing the line `<max-pool-size>0</max-pool-size>`  as explained [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/257721).
   - reload
2. For your version, JBoss EAP 7.0 : Remember to enable the DB:

```
#/subsystem=datasources/data-source=MyExampleDS:enable()                               
#/subsystem=datasources/data-  source=MyExampleDS:test-connection-in-pool()
```